# Repair Marin Hawk Hill (cracked frame) or get new bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, replacement

I have a 2017 or 2018 Marin Hawk Hill. It has a cracked frame (see photo). My local bike shop contacted Marin, who said they have a frame that can be used. It would also require a shock replacement. The total, including labor, would be $750. I am wondering if it is worth it to do this or if I should instead buy a new bike. I don't want to spend a ton of money, so the replacement frame is appealing, but I also don't want to end up wasting money.
[image]

Comment: It's out of warranty right? If so, you have no obligation to stick with Marin.

Comment: Yes, it is out of warranty.

Comment: What level of build did you buy? 1, 2 or 3

Comment: Maybe an experienced welder could weld it? There is a lot of ”meat” in the area (much easier to weld than e.g. tubes with thin walls).

Comment: I looked and it is a 2017 Hawk Hill 1.

Comment: The replacement frame is probably being offered to you at a discouut, most of the big manufacturers do this as a cracked frame doesn't look so great for the reputation, even though it's not uncommon.

Comment: @bill999 What did you end up doing?  Based on that last answer, this is a weak point on this brand/model of frame.  Did you repair it or replace it ?

Comment: @Criggie, I didn't want to risk a catastrophic break, so I got a new frame. My bike shop worked with Marin and got a frame from a newer year. They also had to replace the rear suspension because the original rear suspension was incompatible with the new frame. The price ended up being higher than $750, but it was still better than buying a new bike.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A new similar bike would cost ~1500 €/$/GBP, right?
For half the price, you get a new frame, a new shock, all your old&used parts (in which conditions are they)?

No brainer:
If you think your parts are worth at least 750$ and you can sell them for more than 750$, sell them and then buy a complete new bike.

If you think your parts are worth less than 750$, accept their offer (or find a better deal on a compatible set frame+fork)

Comment: Small corrections: reg the new bike, 
unless you enjoy being without bike in Spring/Summer ;) first buy a complete new bike and then sell the parts (so you bear quite some risk on the capital you invest in the new bike).

If you find a better deal, without the labor, take into account that it may take **a lot** of effort transferring all the parts to the new frame (sum-up: I think 750$ **with** labor is a really good deal)

Answer (score 4):

Wow I one upped you and just broke the whole chainstay completely in two.

Looks like this is a definite weak-point on this brand of frame.

[image]

Based on this, a repair might be a bad idea unless it adds substantial reinforcement to this structural element.

A new frame (of a different model or brand) would be a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to the site - sorry to see your bike is broken in a similar way to OP's.   I'm going to try re-writing your reply to make it more of an answer,   If I change your meaning, please use "revert"   And in the meantime, please brows the [tour] to learn how SE is organised.

Comment: Interesting to see how it didn’t break at the thinnest part.

Comment: @MaplePanda Looks like its the middle of the span, so the "least-supported" part of the stretch

Comment: @Criggie Wouldn’t the middle of the span be like 1.5cm to the left? Coincidentally, that’s also the thinnest part. The break location seems to be on the edge of the weld, which is very interesting.

Comment: @MaplePanda yeah - the two photos are of the same area but slightly different angles.  I was looking at Brian's photo.   But either way, this chainstay seems to be too thin.